# What is the solution of this error: Whoops, something went wrong on our servers?

Tags: laravel

I just have uploaded my project to `000webhost.com` but I am getting a 500 error.

I have tried the way of documentation provided in 000webhost documentation but this was unable to solve my problems.

Answer (score 1):

(from 000webhost community)

1. Interference with `.htaccess` file.
   If you have implemented `.htaccess` on your site, it may be interfering with the web page you are trying to load into your browser. Please double check the `.htaccess` configurations to ensure that it doesn't contain any errors. To confirm if `.htaccess` misconfiguration is the cause of the 500 Internal Server error, either remove or rename the `.htaccess` file.
2. PHP Coding Timing Out
   If your PHP script makes external network connections, the connections may time out. If too many connections are attempted and time out, this will cause the Internal Server Error. To prevent such timeouts and errors, we suggest that your relevant PHP scripts be coded with proper timeout rules.
3. Search on Google for your script name + Internal Server Error. For example if you get this error on WordPress blog - search Google for "WordPress internal server error fix".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have ssh access or not, but http 500 error has many variety reasons but in general it means that your server cant reach/access to the index.php in your public folder so please try this options

1. make sure your folders has the right owner generally its apache for apache servers and nginx for nginx servers
   for example:
   `sudo chown -R apache:apache /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory`
2. make sure your folders and files has the right permissions
   `sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` 
   `sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`
3. if you don't use a shared host make sure your `DocumentRoot` points to a correct folder in your `/etc/httpd/confhttpd.conf` for apache and `root` in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for nginx server
4. check if you can access `http://yoursite.com/index.php` if you did access, then you need add htaccess to your server
   for nginx you need to add `index index.php` in your `nginx.conf`
   and `DirectoryIndex index.php` in your `httpd.conf` in apache servers